# How to check if something exists in a Pyomo model

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo

I'm looking for a pyomo function that will return True if an element exists in a pyomo model.

For example, if I create a simple pyomo model I would want it to respond as follows below. Alternatively, maybe there's a way to output a list of all the elements in a Pyomo model that I can then check for a certain element?

```
import pyomo.environ as pe

model = pe.AbstractModel()
model.t = pe.Set()
model.A = pe.Param(model.t)

# Do functions such as has_element() or list_elements() exist?
model.has_element('A') # Returns True
model.has_element('B') # Returns False

elements = model.list_elements()
print('A' in elements) # Prints True
print('B' in elements) # Prints False
```

The best thing I've come up with so far is to use the find_component() function, which returns the component if it exists and None if it does not

```
import pyomo.environ as pe

model = pe.AbstractModel()
model.t = pe.Set()
model.A = pe.Param(model.t)

model.find_component('A') # Returns model.A
model.find_component('B') # Returns None
```

Is this the best approach?

Comment: Why wouldn´t that be the best approach? As for the list elements, if you check the docs its calles list_components()

Comment: Can you point to which docs you're referring? I cannot find list_components(), but the function component_objects() will return an iterator for all the components in an AbstractModel

Comment: looked at the code: https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pyomo/core/base/component.html?highlight=list_components

Answer (score 1):

Because strings and non-empty objects are typically truthy and None is falsey in python:

```
if model.find_component('A'):
    # do something with model A
    print('here')

if model.find_component('B'):
    # do something with model B
    print('there')
```

Notice if you ran the above scenario you'd get the intended result as "here" would be printed, but "there" would not.